# char array prints wrong value in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf

I am stuck on the same code for quit some time now. I am trying to fill a char array with characters i read from a text file (ascii). But for some reason when i printf the char array it only displays the letter H.

Code:

```
void append(char c)
{
  //int len = strlen(cStr);
  cStr[iCounter] = c;
  cStr[iCounter + 1] = '\0';
  printf("char c:%c    char array%c\n",c,cStr);
}
```

The char array (cStr) is declared outside this function because i need to acces it from different functions. So is iCounter which is incremented every time it executes this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print one character with `%c` use string specifier `%s` instead:

```
printf("char c:%c    char array%s\n",c,cStr);
```

Note: `iCounter` is not actually incremented:

```
  cStr[iCounter++] = c;
  cStr[iCounter] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%s` to print string. `%c` is use to print unique character.

From printf [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

> **c**
>
> If no l modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an
>   unsigned char, and the resulting character is written. If an l
>   modifier is present, the wint_t (wide character) argument is converted
>   to a multibyte sequence by a call to the wcrtomb(3) function, with a
>   conversion state starting in the initial state, and the resulting
>   multibyte string is written.